# Como exibir uma matriz triangular superior?

Tags: python, loop

Escreva um programa que imprima uma matriz 10x10 que seja triangular superior, ou seja, os elementos abaixo da diagonal principal são nulos (ou zero).

Até então consegui fazer isso:

```
for linha in range(10):
    for coluna in range(10):
      if(linha == coluna):
        print("1", and = "/t")
      else:
        if(coluna > linha):
          print("2", end = "\t")
        else:
          print("0", end = "\t")
    print ("\n")
```

Mas ele está dando erro, alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Qual é o erro que está acontecendo? Você poderia [editar sua pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/382375/edit) e formatar o código para que possamos entender melhor o seu problema?

Comment: Revise a linha 4 do seu código. É nela que está dando o erro que você não colocou na pergunta. Compare o que fez nessa linha com as outras e verá o problema.

Answer (score 3):

Na linha 4:

```
print("1", and = "/t")
```

Deve ser substituído por:

```
print("1", end="/t")
```

As mensagens de erro são importantes tanto para você entender o que está acontecendo no seu código quanto para enriquecer sua pergunta. Junto às próximas, experimente colocar as mensagens :)

Answer (score 0):

O subtipo `matriz triangular` só é aplicável à matrizes quadradas. Desse modo, toda e qualquer matriz triangular - superior ou inferior - necessariamente, sempre será uma matriz quadrada.

Segundo [esta definição](https://www.preparaenem.com/matematica/matriz-triangular.htm) uma matriz é `triangular superior`, se e somente se, a matriz quadrada possuir elementos **Aij = 0, para todo i > j**.

Como minha intensão é mostrar como montar e exibir uma matriz triangular superior de ordem qualquer, então poderemos utilizar o seguinte algoritmo abaixo:

```
import numpy as np

while True:
    try:
        m = int(input('Digite a ordem da matriz: '))
        if m < 1:
            print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas valores maiores que "0"!\033[m')
        else:
            break
    except ValueError:
        print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas valores inteiros!\033[m')

lista = list()
for i in range(1, m + 1):
    linha = list()
    for j in range(1, m + 1):
        if i > j:
            linha.append(0)
        else:
            while True:
                try:
                    v = int(input(f'Digite o {j}º valor da {i}ª linha: '))
                    break
                except ValueError:
                    print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas valores inteiros!\033[m')
            linha.append(v)
    lista.append(linha)

matriz = np.array(lista)
print(f'\033[32mA matriz Triangular superior é:\n{matriz}\033[m')
```

Observe que para montar o algoritmo importei a biblioteca `numpay`. Esta, por sua vez, já havia sido instalada anteriormente.

Observe que o primeiro bloco `While True`, captura e trata o valor digitado que representa a ordem da matriz.

Posteriormente, o algoritmo executa o aninhamento de blocos `for`. É, por intermédio deste aninhamento de blocos `for`, que será montada uma lista de listas contendo todos os valores digitados. Em seguida, o método `array` da biblioteca `numpy` organiza a apresentação espacial da lista, produzindo uma matriz na forma tabular.